# git: How to find file history from blob ID

Tags: git, svn, git-log, git-blame

I'm trying to replicate Subversion's `$Id: $` feature with git. I know that I can use `.gitattributes` to set the `ident` attribute, which will allow me to embed the blob ID in a source code comment. That's the basic requirement, and I'm covered.

But I'm struggling to work out how I can make the ID useful in a practical sense. `git log` and `git blame` require a filename, so I can't use the ID with them. `git show` just shows the blob contents, but doesn't give any link to the commit.

What I'd like is, given a blob ID, to get the commit that created that blob. (Ultimately, to get `git log` or `git blame` data for the file, or to be able to check out a revision that contained that file).

I appreciate that commit history in a distributed system like git is more complex than subversion, but if I can get anything as a starting point, that would be sufficient. All I really need is to be able to demonstrate that given the source code, I can track back into the version control history.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601215/finding-a-file-by-its-corresponding-blobs-hash-in-a-git-repository https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33211914/how-to-find-all-uses-of-a-blob-in-a-git-repo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223678/which-commit-has-this-blob

Answer (score 0):

What about git tag command? Check this link as starting point:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the blob id, the [gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#__code_export_subst_code) manual describes an `export-subst` filter, so you could turn that on and use `$Format:%H$` to add the commit hash, or `$Format:%d$` to include branch/tag names. You would have to release the files using `git archive`.

For example:

```
$ cat .gitattributes
* export-subst ident
$ cat foo.c
// Blob hash: $Id$
// Commit hash: $Format:%H%d$
$ git archive master | tar -xO
* export-subst ident
// Blob hash: $Id: 9e0569a55a4eaacdf8d100a2c3d3654cf767650b $
// Commit hash: 3802b7884faf182ce0994ac9d94925dad375be05 (HEAD -> master, tag: v2)
```